# Entity Data Model System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: ado.net-entity-data-model

I am using the entity data model to connect to a database. It works fine locally. When I upload my website to the server it throws the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Non-negative number required.
Parameter name: count
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Non-negative number required.
Parameter name: count

Source Error:

Line 14:             //Fill the Route collection here.
Line 15:             routes.Clear();
Line 16:             foreach (var page in context.PageInfos)
Line 17:             {
Line 18:                 //get the friendly URL


Source File: e:\HostingSpaces\homelink\dev.homelinkfamilysupport.org\wwwroot\Global.asax    Line: 16

Stack Trace:

[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Non-negative number required.
Parameter name: count]
   System.Buffer.BlockCopy(Array src, Int32 srcOffset, Array dst, Int32 dstOffset, Int32 count) +0
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadByteArray(Byte[] buff, Int32 offset, Int32 len) +153
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean& marsCapable) +173
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity) +473
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) +129
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) +164
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +195
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +232
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +33
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +524
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +479
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +108
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +52

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +161
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +98
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() +81
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +46
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +44
   ASP.global_asax.RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) in e:\HostingSpaces\homelink\dev.homelinkfamilysupport.org\wwwroot\Global.asax:16
   ASP.global_asax.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\HostingSpaces\homelink\dev.homelinkfamilysupport.org\wwwroot\Global.asax:7


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

The database on the server definately has the exact same structure and data as it was restored from a .bak file of the original (from which the EDM was generated).

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference sake: this was caused due to my hosting provider changing the port I had to use to connect to SQL server. Not related to the code.